# Symfony Override Command Class from third-party Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, exception, overriding, symfony-console

I have a project in which i am using [JMose's Command Scheduler Bundle](https://github.com/J-Mose/CommandSchedulerBundle) in order to create a cronjob manager. The cronjob Manager handles my own custom Symfony command **parse:source**.

The problem is that this repo is handling Exceptions and throwing errors back on the command console which would be very neat if it included the $e->getLine() method in order for the exception message to be printed along with the line that produced it. 
You can see his code below.

```
    try {
        $output->writeln('<info>Execute</info> : <comment>' . $scheduledCommand->getCommand()
            . ' ' . $scheduledCommand->getArguments() . '</comment>');
        $result = $command->run($input, $logOutput);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $logOutput->writeln($e->getMessage());
        $logOutput->writeln($e->getTraceAsString());
        $result = -1;
    }
```

What I want is to override his class in order add that line of code. I have tried that without luck and I was not able to find help on Symfony documentation site.

My current project structure looks something like that. I have highlighted the class ExecuteCommand because it is the class that I want to override.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run the command in verbose mode:

```
php bin/console parse:source -v
```

Use the Symfony console events:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/console/events.html

There is an event called: `EXCEPTION` or `console.exception` where you can catch any command exception.

Comment: Hello, the problem is that the Exception is already being handled by the JMose Bundle. Furthermore I do not want the exception to be handled by the Console Events. I need the Exception to be handled by JMose so it can be written into the cronlog file that is created for that command execution.